# Limiting API Requests

Tags: php, api

I am trying to figure out the best way to limit API requests for a given key. Basically, I currently have a table field called `counter` where one every request I add 1 to the previous value.So I'm already logging every request but my question is that what is the most efficient way of limiting the output for a user where the limit is determined by `n` number of requests a month.

Now the solution I have at the moment is that you just compare `if counter <= n` and then proceed with getting the data but is there a better way of doing this ? considering that the data is cached and if you are querying the DB on every request for the counter you might as well request the data too..

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store the counter associated with each key directly in memory using something like php memcache. Then you could backup all the values into your database once a day in case of a server failure where you lose the data in memory you will only have lost the counts for part of one day.

Depending on how many keys you give out you would have to determine how much memory this would use and if it is a practical solution.

You could use a middle ground too and only cache the ones that have reached their limit each month. So every time a key reaches it's maximum request count you flag it in memory. Then at the end of each month, when you reset the counts in the db you also flush them all out of memory.

This way you make the requests to your db until the user reaches the limit (since you're querying the db anyways for the request) and then you stop querying the table.

Comment: Hello Paul, this situation is that most of the data is cached for a day so without any throttling implement, for a given request you only query the db for the data just once every 24 hrs and the rest of the time, the data is loaded from a cache file. so what I cant figure out is the best way to make sure if the given request doesnt exceed the `n` amount without get the counter value every single time..

Comment: when I was replying, you only had the 1st paragraph.. didnt see the other 3 until I posted..

Answer (score 1):

Why not store the counters in a separate table? Or even better, instead of using a counter, use an access log with a timestamp. Every time the client uses your service, just do an insert with the client id, and the current date and time. Then all you have to do is query for `COUNT(*) WHERE client_id = 5 AND date_time >= now() - 30 days` (or whatever. not valid SQL I know, gimme a break).

Comment: Presumably an API would get called "many" times, and dynamically counting hits would get expensive very quickly. Probably be far cheaper to increment a counter in a table somewhere, with a periodic reset.

Comment: @Marc: an insert is cheaper than a select followed by an update.

Comment: Hello Chris, the counter are in a separate table and I know; thats what I have too but I am trying to get is a way where I dont have to query the DB as much.. but cant think of any

Comment: Yes, but if the api gets popular, the "hits" table is going to quickly grow very large, and doing a select count(*) will take far longer than a simple update on the user table to increment the counter.

Comment: Hmm... you've given me much to think about.

Comment: I mean I can reset the counters every month but cant figure out a way to cross check the limits without making a call for every request for every key

Comment: Well I'd look at PaulPRO's answer, that seems like a good alternative.