# How to limit cURL connetions

Tags: php, api, rest, soap, curl

i have written a small script to connect via cURL to my API, however, i need to know how i can limit incoming cURL connections to prevent spam.

How can this be done?

```
<?php

function shorten_url($urltoshorten) {

$url = 'http://nn.pe/api.php?url='.$urltoshorten;  


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request); 
// what to post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $result;

}

?>
```

Comment: can you please show here your small script??

Comment: Edit made with code that requests the information from my API. Anyway i can limit connections made by this?

Comment: Make clients to authorize using some credentials. Or keep a track of incoming requests, and block requests from that IP after it crosses a certain threshold, say 10 per hour.

Comment: Use curl_set_opt(CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 10); for limiting connections.

Comment: Yes but people can just change that if they are using cURL to connect to my API, i need to limit it my side.

Comment: You can keep track of connected users (IPs maybe) by writing to memcache, or APC. It will be faster than writing-reading to a database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851757/limiting-api-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: **`curl_set_opt(CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 10);`** for limiting connections you made by curl. Or you can create a table and keep record of IPs requesting for connections.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As that script i have pasted is located on the requesters side, it would allow people to change the max connects, would that cURL you put there be able to go into the PHP API and is that setting max connects for 10, per hour, minute?

Comment: Its not for min or hours, its till when a connection is closed. CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT can be used as the number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.

Comment: What are the possible disadvantages of setting the maximum to be a large number like 1000? Is it just memory usage? Also this is limiting the cache size right? Does it also limit the number concurrent connections?